# Is java.nio.file.PathMatcher thread safe?

Tags: java, nio

The actual implementation is file system specific and an instance of a PathMatcher is likely to have state, so not likely.

Does anyone know for sure?

Answer (score 1):

A [`PathMatcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/PathMatcher.html) seems to be a purely functional interface. The `PathMatcher` accepts a `Path` and returns `boolean`, I can't think of a reason why this processing would need any state that would make it unsafe. The only state it might need would be a fixed(!) pattern, like when created with [`FileSystem.getPathMatcher(java.lang.String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getPathMatcher%28java.lang.String%29)).

As such I'd expect it to be fully threadsafe unless explicitly indicated otherwise.

Comment: Still not an answer, to this specific question, but [`FileSystem` hints that](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html) "File systems are safe for use by multiple concurrent threads," which would also make me expect exceptions to be noted.

Comment: _As such I'd expect it to be fully threadsafe unless explicitly indicated otherwise_  I use the opposite heuristic with Oracle javadocs

Comment: Two implementations I can see, are currently thread safe

 http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/sun/nio/zipfs/ZipFileSystem.java.html
 http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/nio/fs/WindowsFileSystem.java

Comment: @DavidSoroko For classes that are stateful, I agree, but nothing about a `PathMatcher` suggests state.

Comment: I understand why you say what you are saying. Ultimately, the question is, will you have a singleton PathMatcher (for a specific given  pattern) in a production system.